# How to fix error when moving log4net.config in a dot net Core in a non standard place (not the root of the solution)

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

Why does dot net Core create a folder called "netcpreapp3.1" inside Debug and how can I dynamically get to it?
I have added log4net to my dot net Core Web API app, and if I put the log4net.config at the same level as the Startup.cs file, and then in Program.cs I add the ConfigureLogging part like this:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            }).ConfigureLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                builder.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
            });
```

it's all fine, but if I put log4net.config inside of a folder called Config, it is no longer found until I do:

```
builder.AddLog4Net("..\\netcoreapp3.1\\Config\\log4net.config");
```

(not great, because we'll have netcoreapp3.2 in the future, right?)
and then it breaks somewhere else:   `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();` // in Startup.cs, saying it expects \bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\log4net.config (my Config folder is not there in the path).
PS: This implementation is using: using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

So, question is how can I move log4net.config in a non standard place - which isn't same level as Startup.cs?

Comment: Have you tried `builder.AddLog4Net("Config\\log4net.config");`?

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you!  What actually worked was: builder.AddLog4Net("..\\netcoreapp3.1\\Config\\log4net.config"); but I am not happy about the netcoreapp3.1 in the path because I shouldn't have to manually change it later on when we upgrade to 3.2. The error is now at this line: `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();`

Comment: I am sure there must be a configuration thing somewhere when location of log4net.config is not standard

Comment: The problem is not that the path isn't standard, the problem is that your app isn't where you think it is. The folder "netcoreappXXX" is where the binaries are really stored for .net core apps, so "Config\\log4net.config" should be the same as "..\\netcoreapp3.1\\Config\\log4net.config". Check the initial path that VS is using for the project with `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`

Comment: Also, is your file really copied to "netcoreapp3.1\Config\log4net.config"?

Comment: Gusman, file is in: bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Config . Sorry, I made a mistake, `builder.AddLog4Net("Config\\log4net.config"); works ` but still not clear about how to fix `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();`

Comment: Only as a side note: builder.AddLog4Net("\\Config\\log4net.config"); doesn't work - this is what I had tried previously. This would go to the path:'C:\Config\log4net.config'.'

Comment: Yes, "\\" at the beginning of a path specifies the root of the drive, that's normal. Let me write a full answer.

Comment: I got it to work by doing this: loggerFactory.AddLog4Net("Config\\log4net.config");

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!!

Comment: Yep, that's what I was writting in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Config\log4net.config" as the path, no need to add the "netcoreapp3.1" part of the path as that's where the process is started, it's the working path.

So, you need to specify that path to the `builder.AddLog4Net` call and also to the `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net`.